# matplotlib: How to annotate a patch/wedge

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot a ring chart (like [gnome baobab](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/baobab-ringschart.html)).

Currently I'm doing it more or less like this:

```
patches = [
    Wedge((0.5,0.2), .4,  0, 45,  width=0.10, color='r'),
    Wedge((0.5,0.2), .3, 30, 120, width=0.10, color='g'),
    Wedge((0.5,0.2), .2, 60, 180, width=0.10, color='b'),
]

for p in patches:
    ax.add_patch(p)
```

You can see this way I can specify each ring section color.
Now I need to set a label for each ring section;
I guess I can just annotate the axe at (x,y) wedge position.

How can I get each wedge center position?
Is there a better way?

Comment: You know the wedge center, the radius and the wedge angles. You can use these to calculate the center of the wedge

Comment: `theta = pi*(wedge_theta1 + wedge_theta2)/180`
`x = wedge_x + (wedge_radius - wedge_width/2)*cos(theta/2.)`
`y = wedge_y + (wedge_radius - wedge_width/2)*sin(theta/2.)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution is the following:

```
# pip install matplotlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

outer_sizes = [45, 45, 45, 45]
inner_sizes_1 = [90, 90]
inner_sizes_2 = [60, 120]

outer_colors = ['w', 'w', 'w', 'r']
inner_colors_1 = ['w', 'g']
inner_colors_2 = ['w', 'b']

textprops = {'size':12, 'color': 'w'}

plt.pie(outer_sizes, colors=outer_colors, radius=4, startangle=90, autopct='%1.0f%%', pctdistance=0.87, textprops=textprops)
plt.pie(inner_sizes_1, colors=inner_colors_1, radius=3, startangle=60, autopct='%1.0f%%', pctdistance=0.85, textprops=textprops)
plt.pie(inner_sizes_2, colors=inner_colors_2, radius=2, startangle=-15, autopct='%1.0f%%', pctdistance=0.75, textprops=textprops)
center_circle = plt.Circle((0,0), 1, color='black', fc='white', linewidth=0)

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(center_circle)
fig.set_size_inches(5,5)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Returns

[image]